# Imposing special structure on Positive Semi-Definite matrix

Tags: python, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, cvxpy

I am trying to implement the algorithm described in reference 1 using `cvxpy`. However I am struggling to constrain the matrix $Z_j$ as described in equations (33-35). Citing the paper ($\bar{\mu_j}$ is just a vector):

> Remaining constraint on $R_j$ is:
>
> $$Z_j= \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 && (\bar{\mu_j})^{'} \\ \bar{\mu_j} &&
> U \end{matrix} \right]$$
>
> where $U$ must be $\bar{\mu_j}(\bar{\mu_j})^{'}$. since the constraint
>   is not linear, we relax it such that:
>
> $$U-\bar{\mu_j}(\bar{\mu_j})^{'}\succeq 0$$
>
> by the property that:
>
> $$Z_j\succeq0 \Leftrightarrow U-\bar{\mu_j}(\bar{\mu_j})^{'}\succeq0$$
>
> where $Z_j \succeq 0$ denotes that $Z_j$ is positive semi-definite
>   matrix.

I tried to force this structure by doing the following:

```
u = cvx.Variable(D)
U = u*u.T
Zj = cvx.bmat([[1, u.T], [u, U]])
```

However `cvxpy` complains that `u*u.T` is incorrect:

`UserWarning: Forming a nonconvex expression (affine)*(affine).`

And solver fails:

`cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules`

It appears that outer product of two vectors cannot be implemented as such. Any ideas on how to enforce this constraint?

#### References

1. Yun, Sungrack, and Chang D. Yoo. ["Loss-scaled large-margin Gaussian mixture models for speech emotion classification."](https://groups.google.com/group/cvxpy/attach/190960cf8d135/05957267.pdf?part=0.1&authuser=0) IEEE Transactions on Audio, Speech, and Language Processing 20.2 (2012): 585-59

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point is that you do NOT include the constraint $U = uu^T$ .  That constraint is non-convex.

Instead you include the constraint that $Z_j$ is (positive) semi-definite. This constraint is a convex relaxation of $U = uu^T$, obtained by Schur complement.  I.e., the relaxed constraint, which is convex, is used instead of the original non-convex constraint.